# Search files in subfolder and export results to file

Tags: find, grep, pipe

I have a folder with hundreds of subfolders. I need to locate recursively within the subfolders those that don't have certain files inside (for instance *ch.pdf or *.jpg) and export the results to a txt file.
Thx in advance

Comment: have no fear executing the below command, it cannot harm your files ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

`find <folder> -type d -exec bash -c "ls {} | grep -i \".*ch\.pdf$\|.*\.jpg$\" > /dev/null || echo {}" \; > <target file>`

Brief explanation:

1. list all folders inside <folder> recursively
2. for each folder found - list all files and check whether there are any that end with "ch.pdf" or ".jpg". We are not interested in these files, so redirect the output to /dev/null.
3. If there were no such files found, print relative folder path with `echo`.
4. redirect the results of `find` to <target file>

Comment: will try this tomorrow and reply back.just to check, there may be a problem with case sensitive files, probably there are some with capital letters. a -i or something somewhere at the command perhaps? thanks

Comment: @Celso.Baia yes, you are right. If different case letters are expected we need to add '-i' option to grep - fixed the command accordingly.

Comment: works as expected :)